# How to post data from angularJS to codeigniter by header and body

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have a problem in my duty, this afternoon I must send this duty to my lecture.

I must post data from `angularjs` to `codeigniter` by header and body, but when I try to post I always get error like this:

> Failed to load http://api.myduty.com/member/register: Request header
>   field DeviceID is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

This is my `angular script (service)`, please correct my script, maybe there is error in my script.

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])

.factory('DutyService', function($http, $window) {

  function _authorize(isLogin, MobileSession) {
    if(isLogin) {
      return {
        DeviceID: "8888888888",
        Authorization: "GJ5eWZGUERRVjBReVRQR25WbzVQWVBvMHUwUnhjbUg",
        PushToken: "AAAAAAAAAAAA",
        ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        MobileSession: MobileSession
      }
    }else{
      return {
        DeviceID: "8888888888",
        Authorization: "GJ5eWZGUERRVjBReVRQR25WbzVQWVBvMHUwUnhjbUg",
        PushToken: "AAAAAAAAAAAA",
        ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 
      }
    }        
  }

   function register(data) {
    return $http({
      method: "post",
      url: 'http://api.myduty.com/member/register',
      data: {
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        name: data.name,
        birthday: data.birthday,
        phone: data.phone
      },
      headers: _authorize(false)
    });
  }

 return {
    register: register
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Request header field DeviceID is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response?**

If it's not allowed, then allow it on the server-side.

If you use e.g. PHP on the server then put this header on the requested resurs:

header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DeviceID');